# Cannot logon with credentials obtained from Secure Store Provider

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I was able to set all the required permissions through the central administration and create external content types. Every thing was working fine and all the users were able to view the external lists as well. But all of a sudden I get this error while accessing the external lists "Cannot logon with credentials obtained from Secure Store Provider".
Can anyone please help me understand this error and resolve it.
Thanks